# Filter complains about objects being left active

Tags: c++, directshow

How do I find out which objects in a directshow filter have not been deleted?

Comment: It's C++ code, all regular debugging techniques apply.

Comment: Without some samplecode and more information on what you are doing you will only get standard answers like "use a debugger and break in the destructur"!

Answer (score 0):

See [Enumerating Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page in MSDN with some code that can tell you what filters are still in the graph.